# Keeping Hidden Console Active

Tags: c#, console, lync

I've developed a console application to wait for an event. The main part of the code looks like the following.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // get lync client
    var getclient = LyncClient.GetClient();  
    // register for conversation event
    getclient.ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += Conversation_ConversationAdded;
}
```

What I wish for is to run this in the background, therefore I've changed its output to windows application. But it seems that the application ends once it is launched. Is there a way to keep the application alive?

Obviously I cannot use `Console.Readline()` since I wish to hide it. For now I'm using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue)`, but I don't think it's a good idea anyway since there's a limit to it.

Not sure if the issue lies within my code, or I just need something to keep it alive. Any pointers?

Comment: have you ever stopped to think that the application ends once launched because there is an Error ..?

Comment: I've already tested it when the output is set to console application, everything works when there's a console window. I just wanted the same thing to happen without the window. I apologize for not knowing it all because I just started to learn this. I just wanted to know if I missed out anything.

Comment: That's all very nice, but when do you *want* your application to end? If never and the Lync client is happy running in another thread, just use `Thread.Sleep (Timeout.Infinite)`.

Comment: Ahh, that's neat. Tested and it worked. That solves the time limitation I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it as a WPF application with a hidden main window that has the property ShowInTaskbar = false.  That way it will interact with the Lync Client and not show up on the user's desktop.

Comment: Merci! That's one thing I haven't thought of. Probably will implement it for further improvement after I'm done with the basic functions.